# How to add an image to a table with an if statement in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I got something like this:

```html
<tr bgcolor="lightgrey">
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="s in schools| filter:searchField | orderBy:'schoolId'"
    ng-click="selectSchool(s, $index)"
    ng-class="getSelectedClass(s)">
  <td>{{s.schoolId}}</td>
  <td>{{s.schoolName}}</td>
</tr>
```

Ok, now that school has an int parameter, and now I want to add a simple image (green and/or red dot) to my table...but if the parameter is 0 it should be the red dot else it should be the green one...

So is it possible to do it somehow with an if statement in angular?
And if yes, i need it to be clickable, so once i press the red dot, it should become green and vice versa.

Comment: where you place the image?

Comment: i have my images in the project, web content, images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use ng-if="parameter === 0"

    <img> red dot image

ng-if="parameter!==0"

    <img> green dot image
```

Or you may also do

```
<img ng-src="{{parameter===0?'reddotsrc' : 'greendotsrc'}}" ng-click="parameter!=parameter">
```

If parameter is 0 then it toggle 1 and if 1 then it to 0.

Comment: if it need to be clickable, add an ng-click directive with a function to switch between the values 'reddotsrc' and 'greendotsrc'.

Comment: when i do this <td><img ng-src="{{s.timerPeriod.timerRepeat===0?"images\red.png" : "images\green.png"}}" ng-click="parameter!=parameter"></td> it does not show the image

Comment: Check the path you are providing for image.
And also check the url in call header in network to verify whether it points to desired location or not.
Also change   "parameter" with your "s.timerPeriod.timerRepeat"

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-show :

Html:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
       <table>
        <tr ng-repeat = "data in comments">
        <td>{{data.type}}, {{data.type == 1}}</td>

            <td ng-show="data.type == 1 ">
             <img style="height:10px; width:10px;  padding:5px;" src="http://greensportsalliance.org/images/darkGreenSquare.gif">  
            </td>
            <td ng-show="data.type == 0 ">
               <img style="height:10px; width:10px; padding:5px;" src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/04854427-89c9-48dc-bb5b-9705e0a298b5/6cb7bccb-3dcd-4af2-8da8-8c6260f2f934.jpg">  
            </td> 
        </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.comments = [
        {type:1},{type:0},{type:0},{type:1}
    ]
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2nuo26s5/)

Comment: @Mistalis: yeah, i just tried with ng-show first, ng-if is  better in this case

Answer (score 1):

this may help you

```
<tr bgcolor="lightgrey">
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="s in schools| filter:searchField | orderBy:'schoolId'"
    ng-click="selectSchool(s, $index)"
    ng-class="getSelectedClass(s)">
  <td ng-if="s.parameter == 0"><img src='reddot.png' ng-click="s.parameter = 1"></td>
  <td ng-if="s.parameter != 0"><img src='greendot.png' ng-click="s.parameter = 0"></td>
  <td>{{s.schoolId}}</td>
  <td>{{s.schoolName}}</td>
</tr>
```